# Does the VMX mode have the capability to detect previously non-trappable sensitive instructions?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture, processor

Does the VMX mode provide a Virtualisation Systems Architect with the capability to detect previously non-trappable sensitive instructions?

Comment: You mean like CPUID?  I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say yes. According to pages 13 through 17 of [this *Virtualization and Virtual Machines* presentation](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~ychung/slides/Virtualization/Intel%20VT.pptx), hardware virtualization seems to be an attempt to solve that problem.

The [pdf @prl posted](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-s14/lectures/L30_Virtualization.pdf) also says on slide 45:

> if a guest kernel runs a sensitive instruction, hardware does a 'VM exit' back to the VMM, indicates which instruction trapped

Comment: @pleft: Seems fine to me. This post isn't saying, "Look for the answer at this here address", it does provide a direct answer to the question as asked. Curiously, it even includes essential parts from the provided links.

Comment: Yes, hardware virtualization is specifically to solve this problem, but it does not solve it by trapping on all sensitive instructions, as shown by the examples in my answer.

Comment: The slide set I referenced is an overview, not a precise description or specification.

Answer (score 4):

No, not in all cases. Instead VMX mode changes the behavior of some of these instructions so that they are not sensitive.

Here are a couple examples of how sensitive instructions behave in VMX non-root mode:

- `SMSW`: it doesn't trap when in VMX mode, but it substitutes
  values specified by the VMM for the actual values of certain bits.
- `POPF`: the behavior of the instruction doesn't change, but control of
  interrupts can be overridden by controls in the VMCS, to prevent
  guest changes to IF from affecting the VMM or other guests.

This reference has a list of sensitive x86 instructions on page 28: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-s14/lectures/L30_Virtualization.pdf. Volume 3, chapter 25 of the Intel SDM has a detailed description of the change in behavior of every instruction.